# Accessing value in an Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

I've been working on a simple test project, but i happened to come across this really weird problem. I can't access values in an array.

```
pokemonStats$: Observable<PokemonStats[]>;

getPokemonStats(id: number): any {
this.pokemonStats$
.pipe(take(1))
.subscribe(stats => {
  console.log(stats instanceof Array);
  console.log('length', stats.length);
  console.log('du', stats);
  console.log('test', stats[1]);
});
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Output in browser console]

What's going on here? A colleague suggested it might be an array-like structure, that's why i added the 'instanceof' log. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here's the code, where it gets filled

```
this.pokemonStats$ = this.getAllPokemonStats(ids);

getAllPokemonStats(ids: number[]): Observable<PokemonStats[]> {
const pokemonArray: PokemonStats[] = [];
ids.forEach(id => {
  const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + id;
  this.http.get(url)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((data: PokemonStatsAPI) => {
      pokemonArray.push({
          id: data.id,
          name: data.name,
          speed: data.stats[0].base_stat,
          hp: data.stats[5].base_stat,
          attack: data.stats[4].base_stat,
          defense: data.stats[3].base_stat
        });
    });
});
return of(pokemonArray);
```

}

Comment: `pokemonStats$: Observable<PokemonStats[]>` In this line you clearly states that `pokemoStats$` is Observable of `PokemonStats[]` in type definition

Comment: And that's why i subscribed to it, to access the array. But why is it showing length: 0 and why can't I access any of the values, even though they are clearly there when console.logging the entire object?

Comment: The 2nd log entry is interesting as it shows `length 0` but it should be 5 from your next log. Can you show the code where the array is actually created? Or a reproducable example.

Comment: try doing `JSON.stringify(stats)` and add this json to your question so we can see the raw data in `stats`.

Comment: Can you try to remove `take(1)`, and then see whats the result.

Comment: @Viqas is right, i just noticed, you probably fill the array AFTER the console.logs. So it is empty when the log actually happens but the browsers will always show the latest values when you expand it in the log. That is why it logs 0 and stats[1] is undefined but console.log('du', stats); shows the entries

Comment: @GaurangDhorda same result :/

Comment: @x4rf41 I added the code, you can check it.

Comment: @Viqas for some reason 'JSON.stringify(stats)' returns just '[]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the new observable with the `pokemonArray`, which is empty and will be filled async, therefore when you subscribe to `getAllPokemonStats` it's empty.

Use the `forkJoin` operator to perform the http requests and map them using the `map` operator:

```
getAllPokemonStats(ids: number[]): Observable<PokemonStats[]> {
  return forkJoin(ids.map(id => {
    return this.http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
  })).pipe(
    map(results => results.map(data => ({
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      speed: data.stats[0].base_stat,
      hp: data.stats[5].base_stat,
      attack: data.stats[4].base_stat,
      defense: data.stats[3].base_stat
    }))),
  );
}
```